# Can someone explain to why runAnimation() is not accesible when called from the click handler $('#sm_logo')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've cut down some code here to post and find out why runAnimation() is not accesible to the $('#sm_logo') event handler? Is it because it is a self initiating function? I can get around the issue, but I'm really interested to know the workings of why the call can't be made.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var $boxes = $('.box').hide(), div = 0, loop = 0, t;

(function runAnimation (){

    $($boxes[div++] || []).animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, '10',  function(){
        $(this).hide();
        if(div != $boxes.length) {
            $('.style-7').hide('10');
            runAnimation();
    }
    else {
        $('.style-7').show();
        div=0;
        (loop < companies.length -1) ? ++loop : loop = 0;
        t = setTimeout(function(){
            runAnimation();
        }, 2000);
   }    
   });
})()


$('#sm_logo').toggle(function(){
    if( $($boxes).is(':animated') ) 
       $($boxes).stop();
else if ( $('.style-7').is(':visible'))
    clearTimeout(t);
}, function() {
         runAnimation(); //why does this not find the function?
    //location.href = location.href; //this is how I worked around the prob, but 
        //i don't like the fact that the animation restarts from 0
});
```

}); //end doc ready

Answer (score 2):

You hid it from the global namespace by putting `()` around its declaration.

Remove them and it will be there.

Comment: That makes sense - so I just need to call it separately in the first instance instead of it calling itself - thanks.